# External Storage Not Mounted

Tags: java, android

I am still quite new to Android development. I'm trying to take a photo using the camera and save it to the devices storage. The app was crashing and after debugging I realised it's because the devices external storage is not mounted. How do I handle this? Can I mount the storage or is my app just unable to store data on this particular device?

Thanks

Update:

There was an answer chosen to this question but it seems to have been deleted... It linked me to these docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and not hard coded strings.

Some systems use /sdcard and some /mnt/sdcard or even /mnt/sdcard2.. Since you didn't post any code I cannot be sure if this solves the issue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: And have you tried testing the app unplugged from the computer? Some devices mount the storage to your pc and you have to "disconnect" from computer to free the storage. Usually Android displays a persistent notification in the notification drawer where you can unmount it from the computer.